# counting rows of sqlite INSERT SELECT

Tags: sqlite, select, insert, rowcount

I have two sqlite tables, where one table has a foreign key of the other.

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, value TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE b (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, a INTEGER REFERENCES a (id) NOT NULL, value TEXT NOT NULL);
```

I am doing an `INSERT` with a `SELECT` into `b`.

```
INSERT INTO b (a, value) SELECT ?value, a.id FROM a WHERE a.value == ?a;
```

How do I know weather a row was inserted into b or not? Doing a `SELECT` for the just inserted values and checking weather they exist, seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the [changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes) function can help you.

> The changes() function returns the number of database rows that were
>   changed or inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT,
>   DELETE, or UPDATE statement, exclusive of statements in lower-level
>   triggers. The changes() SQL function is a wrapper around the
>   [sqlite3_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) C/C++ function and hence follows the same rules for
>   counting changes.

So changes() returns 1 if a row was inserted and 0 otherwise.